# showing text in div without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

In the following code, I have a contact form and in that form there is an email validation script. As a result of validation, I want the error message to be shown in a `div` called confirmation without reloading the page. Also, if the email is valid, the mail will be sent and I want the Thank you message to be shown in the same `div` confirmation. The problem is what can I do to prevent reloading the page and let the error message or the thanks message shows in the confirmation div?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function spamcheck($field) {
  // Sanitize e-mail address
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  // Validate e-mail address
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
?>

<?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback"><br>
  <div id="confirmation" style="display:none" align="center"></div>
  </form>
  <?php 
} else {  // the user has submitted the form
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
    // Check if "from" email address is valid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["from"]);
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
      echo"
      <script>
        document.getElementById('confirmation').text ='invalid email';
      </script>";
    } else {
      $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
      $subject = $_POST["subject"];
      $message = $_POST["message"];
      // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
      $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
      // send mail
      mail("nawe11@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
      echo"
      <script>
        document.getElementById('confirmation').text ='Thank you';
      </script>";
    }
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could do what you want using Ajax

Comment: you will need to submit the form using AJAX, then you will get the response and show appropriate absolute positioned divs (error messages, thank you messages)

Comment: `document.getElementById('confirmation').innerHTML = '<div>test</div>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="from" id ="from">
```

Call example:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "file.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { email : $('#from').val() }
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  //handle HTML
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  //Handle problem at server side
});
```

PHP Side

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"]

function spamcheck($field) {
  // Sanitize e-mail address
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  // Validate e-mail address
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return 'valid';
  } else {
    return 'no_valid';
  }
}

echo spamcheck($email);
```

Comment: Note on this: I have no tried the code, this is just a guidance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you could do that with *just PHP*.

What you're looking at is commonly known as AJAX, and uses client-side language (Javascript)
It's very common, and widely used on the internet. You can find many examples and production-ready scripts by searching `ajax` on google.

More informations here : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/